# Windows forwarding PyQt5 GUI from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5, x11-forwarding

I developed a simple GUI using PyQt5, which I would like to run on a remote server from PyCharm using the remote host deployment tools. The source code for a simple GUI to display a blank window is provided below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I ssh into this host from a terminal using X11 forwarding (-Y) and run the GUI (`python3 myapp.py`), the program works fine and a blank window appears as expected. However, if I run the program from PyCharm (using the same Python interpreter on the remote host), I receive the following error:

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
>
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Within PyCharm, I am running the script on the remote host using the same Python interpreter tested in the successful demonstration mentioned above in the terminal using `ssh -Y`. I also set the environment variables in PyCharm in Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Console>Python Console>Environment Variables. I ensured that the DISPLAY environment variable matches the DISPLAY variable when I ssh into the remote host (localhost:10.0). I tried changing the platform plugin to one of the others recommended (setting the `qt_qpa_platform` environment variable), and although some platform plugins do not produce the above error, the expected window does not appear.

I have seen similar posts with this error, however I don't think that the typical recommended solutions of reinstalling pyqt or moving library paths applies to this situation because the program can run outside of PyCharm. I assume that there must be an issue with the PyCharm run configuration environment variables, but I believe that I am setting everything correctly:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
QT_DIR=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3
QTINC=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include
QTLIB=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Use command: export DISPLAY=:0 in terminal
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64085911/vscode-plotting-from-remote-server-issue-qt-qpa-xcb-could-not-connect-to-displ/66266973#66266973

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to my own question, but this is not necessarily ideal. If the program is run from PyCharm with the aforementioned environment variables set *and* I have connected to the remote host using `ssh -Y` from a terminal, the GUI window will be displayed with no errors. If I kill the ssh connection from the terminal, I will not be able to execute the program from PyCharm.

This workaround works for me at the moment, and I wanted to post this in case anyone else stumbles upon this question in the future, but I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand why this workaround works, or how to solve this issue without having to open a separate ssh connection from a terminal.