# VSCode plotting from remote server issue: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display

Tags: python, qt, visual-studio-code, x11, x11-forwarding

**Request from my local VSCode is something look like this:**

```
Host XXX.XX.XX.XXX
  HostName XXX.XX.XX.XXX
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/Key.pem
  User ubuntu
```

On the server, I enabled `X11Forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

Still, I am getting this error

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0.0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not
> load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in
> "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"
> even though it was found. This application failed to start because no
> Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
> may fix this problem.
>
> Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, minimal, minimalegl,
> offscreen, vnc.

**Note:** I am using the integrated terminal of VSCode for running a python script.

Comment: This seems very similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086612/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-in-vscode-integrated-terminal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add command in VSC terminal: export DISPLAY=:0

[image: Solution]