# How to enable x11 forwarding in vscode integrated terminal?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, x11, vscode-remote, x11-forwarding

X11 forwarding working fine in ubuntu's terminal. but if I try to run any GUI from a remote in my VSCode terminal, it shows `: cannot connect to X server`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using the menubar `run` and `run without debugging` option.
Just we need to configure the `launch.json` file and open a terminal from the client pc with this command `ssh -Y -i ~/.ssh/Key.pem username@server`.

In my case `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "args": ["--target", "dataset", "--output", "dataset_softmax", "--nChannel", "32", "--minLabels", "8", "--filetype", "png"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "DISPLAY": "localhost:10.0"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you want a more in-depth step through this might help, keep in mind the IP should be the display host. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging